# XUnit Test with autofac

Tags: autofac, xunit2

I followed this link https://github.com/dennisroche/xunit.ioc.autofac to create XUnit Test with autofac, but I got error

> The requested service 'Xunit.Sdk.TestOutputHelper' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
>   I have added below code:

```
        builder.Register(context => new TestOutputHelper())
            .As<ITestOutputHelper>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Did I miss anything from above link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR:

Make sure to register the type `TestOutputHelper` also as self when using this library.

Longer version:

The `AutofacTestInvoker` (https://github.com/dennisroche/xunit.ioc.autofac/blob/master/src/xunit2.ioc.autofac/AutofacTestInvoker.cs) needs the concrete class `TestOutputHelper` (not `ITestOutputHelper`!) to call `TestOutputHelper.Initialize(IMessageBus, ITest)`, which is not available in the Interface, and resolves it via the created `ILifetimeScope`. In your example you register it as it's interface, so for Autofac there is no TestOutputHelper available to resolve at all.

EDIT: The documentation has been adapted. See https://github.com/dennisroche/xunit.ioc.autofac/pull/9 for details.

Comment: I registered it as ` builder.RegisterType<TestOutputHelper>().AsSelf().As<ITestOutputHelper>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();`

Answer (score 0):

You are registering *ITestOutputHelper*, not *TestOutputHelper* and it seems that the later is required by some constructor.

If you are using TestOutputHelper in some test you should replace it with ITestOutputHelper.

Comment: I did not use TestOutputHelper, I used ITestOutputHelper, it seems there is somewhere in the library uses TestOutputHelper